# Efficiently programming array elements to add up to a sum in python

Tags: python

I'm looking to implement in python a simple algorithm which takes as input an array and a sum, and finds a number *X* where if all elements in the array > *X* are converted to *X*, all the elements in the array should add up to the sum.

How do I do this efficiently?

Here is my code:

```
result = []
for _ in range(int(raw_input())):
     input_array = map(int,raw_input().split())
     sum_target = raw_input()
     for e in input_array:
        test_array = input_array
        test_array[test_array > e] = e // supposed to replace all elements > e with e, but what's wrong here?
        if sum(test_array) == sum_target:
            result.append(e)

print result
```

Comment: Show me yours and I'll show you mine. [mcve] please

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: I have updated my question with my existing code.

Comment: Consider what you are looking to do, remove the `n` highest numbers from the total and add back `n * smallest_number_removed`, keep incrementing `n` until your `current_total` is less than the `target`. Then you know that `X` is `smallest_number_removed + (target - current_total)//(n-1)` (assuming a whole number solution).

Answer (score 0):

Using the Numpy library (`import numpy`), you could replace the line

```
 input_array = map(int,raw_input().split())
```

with

```
 input_array = numpy.array(raw_input().split()).astype(int)
```

Then

```
    test_array[test_array > e] = e
```

just works. Then, you could also do `test_array.sum()`.

(That is, if you want to alter the array in-place, else you could replace

```
    test_array = input_array
```

with

```
    test_array = np.array(input_array)
```